# Remove number references in a text

Tags: python, nlp

I have a text that includes numbered references. For example:

```
text = 'The number of catastrophes caused by natural hazards increased from 249 in 1980 to 820 in 2019, peaking at 848 in 2018. Adjusting for inflation, overall economic losses increased from around USD 60 billion in 1980, to USD 150 billion in 2019, with a peak of USD 350 billion in 2018.[1]  According to the Intergovernmental Panel on Climate Change, global warming of 1.5°C above pre-industrial times is likely to bring about substantial changes in our climate, increasing the likelihood of more extreme weather conditions.[2]  As a result, insurance and economic losses caused by climate-related events are likely to start trending upwards as a share of GDP.[3]'
```

How I can remove all such references [1] , [2], [3] ... etc from a text in python ?

Please note that I don't know the exact number of `[x]` where `x`any number. So, I am seeking the most general solution possible.

Thanks

Comment: `re.sub(r"\[\d+\]", "", text)` [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) [`\[\d+\]`](https://regex101.com/r/KY71wF/1)

Comment: Do you want to remove them or replace them such that "1" becomes "one"?

Answer (score 1):

not robust as using regex but simple enough

```
text :str = 'The number of catastrophes caused by natural hazards increased from 249 in 1980 to 820 in 2019, peaking at 848 in 2018. Adjusting for inflation, overall economic losses increased from around USD 60 billion in 1980, to USD 150 billion in 2019, with a peak of USD 350 billion in 2018.[1]  According to the Intergovernmental Panel on Climate Change, global warming of 1.5°C above pre-industrial times is likely to bring about substantial changes in our climate, increasing the likelihood of more extreme weather conditions.[2]  As a result, insurance and economic losses caused by climate-related events are likely to start trending upwards as a share of GDP.[3]'
inside_ref: bool  = False
new_text = []
for c in text:
    if c == '[':
        inside_ref = True
        continue
    elif c == ']':
        inside_ref = False
        continue
    if not inside_ref:
        new_text.append(c)
print(''.join(new_text))
```

output

```
The number of catastrophes caused by natural hazards increased from 249 in 1980 to 820 in 2019, peaking at 848 in 2018. Adjusting for inflation, overall economic losses increased from around USD 60 billion in 1980, to USD 150 billion in 2019, with a peak of USD 350 billion in 2018.  According to the Intergovernmental Panel on Climate Change, global warming of 1.5°C above pre-industrial times is likely to bring about substantial changes in our climate, increasing the likelihood of more extreme weather conditions.  As a result, insurance and economic losses caused by climate-related events are likely to start trending upwards as a share of GDP.
```

Comment: What about `text = "[1] text [text [2] [blah] [3] finish"`? :-)

Comment: @OlvinRoght your example will break the code for sure :-) The question is if this is a real problem in the current usecase. For one who is not familiar with regex your solution might be unclear.

Comment: You can add [this](https://tio.run/##dVDNCgIhEL77FIOnlWLp5xIL9SIiYWmsYLaoUT39pru5U1Rz0MH5/pzuEduLW2863/dR3yNsgfKlgKHn47kSwA9WtulaCzgZZ0JLCQlR@rg36p44GViniaoop4xYGcpEO/XqFsTrcLWDBSW31lgNqLFLAJBOTYT80BBIhRJvNoLOkc0GnDkhGWejRq6vwL4kfpOaFw028ZJuhnPkz2DZFJyoTVD6aM7SVgzNcr3@OxvteNlKg27iA/9jbcnpf36MP2X@ZylI542L1Thnff8E) option which is a bit more stable.

Comment: @OlvinRoght. As I said - regex is the most elegant solution here. The code in the example you shared adds more complexity in order to remove [number_only]. At the end of the day - it depends on the OP needs.

Comment: I get this error when I try your solution: ``name 'inside_ref' is not defined``

Comment: `inside_ref` is declared on line 2. so it looks like you changed the code somehow - isnt it?

Comment: yep. sorry. My mistake. It worked

Comment: @msh855 Great. Read the discussion above and be aware of the limitations of this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex

```
import re


re.sub("\[.{0,10}\]","",text)
```

Comment: it won't work with numbers with more than one digit.

Comment: Yes, does not work with more than one digit.

Comment: change for re.sub("\[.{0,10}\]","",text) from 0 to 10 digits, replace 10 with any number

Comment: @jeremex, that's bad suggestion, because `.` will match any character, not just digits. Optimal regular expression provided in my comment under question and in attached question.

Comment: OK I understand I'm answering some questions now sorry we can switch to
re.sub("\[[0-9]{0,}\]","",text)

Comment: @jeremex, `\d` is an equivalent of `[0-9]`, `*` is an equivalent of `{0,}`, `+` is and equivalent of `{1,}`

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution.

The `max_num_in_bracket` parameter is the maximum number that can be in the bracket. This is there so the is a limit as to how many times it can run.

```
def remove_brackets(max_num_in_bracket, string):
    for i in range(max_num_in_bracket):
        while f"[{i}]" in string:
            index = string.index(f"[{i}")
            li = [x for x in string]
            li.pop(index)
            li.pop(index)
            li.pop(index)
            string = "".join(li)
    return string
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: It's not a solution, it's more bruteforce with terrible efficiency.